# Why is my Flashlight Turning off when clicking a button with intent function?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-camera

I am new to android programming and I don't understand why my flashlight is turning off when clicking a button that starts another `Activity` with an `Intent`? I have searched for this but found nothing similar. I looked at others' ideas but the closest one is to use a `Service`  instead of an `Activity` from my main activity. Is it okay to change my `Activity` to a `Service` or is another way to resolve this?

```
 tbOnOff = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togglebutton);

 tbOnOff.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new     CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
 public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
         boolean isChecked) {
     if (isChecked) {
         if (camera == null) {
             camera = Camera.open();
             parameters = camera.getParameters();
             parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
             camera.setParameters(parameters);
         }
     } else {
         if (camera != null) {
             parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
             camera.setParameters(parameters);
             camera.release();
             camera = null;
         }
     }
 }
 });

 boolean checkFlash = context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
     PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);
 if (!checkFlash) {
 tbOnOff.setEnabled(false);
 Toast.makeText(context, "LED Not Available!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
         .show();
 }
}

// release camera when onPause called

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    if (camera != null) {
        parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        camera.setParameters(parameters);
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }
}

public void send(View arg1) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, InformationActivity.class);         
    startActivity(i);
}
```

that's my code for LED light and the Intent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you start a new `Activity` it will be brought to the foreground straight away, which means that you're original `Activity` will be paused straight away too. Since you're turning off the flashlight in your `onPause()`, well that's what it does.

As to your other question, yes, if you want the flashlight to stay on independent of the `Activity` [lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle), a `Service` would be a way to do this, as anything else you want to be independent of `Activity` lifecycles.

Comment: will my application behave like it is on extends Activity if i will replace it with extends Service?

Comment: No, a `Service` is different from an `Activity`, you may want to read up on [services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) in the Android docs.

Comment: yeah i have read the docs so the service doesn't have UI unlike Activity and i think most applicable with widgets. how can i resolve my issue the other way?

Comment: Which "other" way? Without using a `Service`? With great difficulty. You could not release the camera in `onPause()`, but that leads to other issues, since you probably want to release it at some stage. You could use an `Activity` _and_ a `Service`, and communicate between them. But this is getting fairly broad now.